# How to Post JSON in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, webserver

This is the first time I will post data on server, I have the request format and I try to send a request but I get error response.
The below is the request:

```
{
    jsonrpc : 2.0,
    method : newPatient,
    params : {
    data : {
first_name : <string>,
    middle_name : <string>,     //optional
    last_name : <string>,           //optional
    id_number : <string>,           //optional
    age : <int>,                //optional
    phone : <string>,           //optional
    city : <string>,            //optional
    country_id : <string>,
    address_line : <string>,        //optional
    email : <string>,
    password : <string>         //hash
}
}
id : 0
}
```

I make the below request but I can't post to the server!!
Can you help me to make correct request?

```
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\n\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\n\"method\":\"newPatient\",\n\"params\": { \n\"data\": {\n\"first_name\":\"%@\",\n\"country_id \":\"%@\",\n\"email\":\"%@\",\n\"password\":\"%@\"\n} \n}\n \"id\":\"0\"\n}",UserName.text,UserCountry.text,Emailtextview.text,Password.text];
    NSLog(@"%@ jsonreq",jsonRequest);


    jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&json_data=%@",jsonRequest];

    NSData *json_data = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody: json_data];

    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[json_data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[[jsonRequest stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]
                          dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                          allowLossyConversion:YES]];

   NSURLConnection* passwordConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    NSLog(@"passconn%@",passwordConnection);
       NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *err;

       NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];
    NSLog(@"Res%@",responseData);

  // NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err ];
   NSString* ResultString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //resultString is the returned buffer from calling the page
    NSLog(@"error:%@", err);
    NSLog(@"this is what the server sends:%@",Result
```

String);

The jsonRequest string in consol is:

```
{
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"method":"newPatient",
"params": { 
"data": {
"first_name":"hh",
"country_id ":"Dd",
"email":"ss",
"password":"Dd"
} 
}
 "id":"0"
} 
}
```

Comment: 1) If you get an error response from the server then you should add the error message to your question. - 2) Your JSON request is invalid (check at http://jsonlint.com). - 3) Use NSJSONSerialization instead of creating the JSON data "manually".

Comment: Thank you Martin R for reply, I get unknown response, you mean by JSON request is invalid that the jsonrequest string is incorrect, to write  NSJSONSerialization it should be nsdictionary! can you help to convert string to dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Your error is that you are missing a number of commas when you create `jsonRequest` string so you end up with invalid (so not parseable) JSON. While you can fix this, it isn't pretty or maintainable to work in this way.

Instead, create a number of dictionaries which form the request content you want to send and use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert the top level dictionary into the data payload to send.

Note that when creating your dictionaries and populating then you should validate the source data as it is coming from (user entry in) text fields and could contain invalid content.

Finally, reconsider why you are using a synchronous connection to send the data and where this will be triggered from. If the user is triggering this upload and it runs on the main thread the app will not be responsive while the upload is processed and that leads to bad user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Fo converting your dictionary to json you need to use the below api. Inside obj parameter pass your above dictionary object.

```
+ (NSData *)dataWithJSONObject:(id)obj options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)opt error:(NSError **)error
```